# Change href depending on viewport size (without jquery)

Tags: javascript, viewport

I want to be able to change a href depending upon window width: on initial page load and window resize (without jquery or other external libraries).
Thank you

HTML

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://highresolutionurl">My Link</a>
```

JS

```
if (screen.width < 768) {
    document.getElementById('myLink').setAttribute('href', "http://highresolutionurl");
}
else if {
    document.getElementById('myLink').setAttribute('href', "http://lowresolutionurl");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screen.width` doesn't change unless you change the display settings on your computer or mobile device. If you want this link to change dynamically with the width of the *window*, you need either `window.innerWidth` or `window.outerWidth`.

If you want this to change dynamically, you can't just do it once, you need to monitor changes in window size.

```
var myLink = document.getElementById('myLink');

function setLink() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    myLink.setAttribute('href', "http://highresolutionurl");
  }
  else {
    myLink.setAttribute('href', "http://lowresolutionurl");
  }
}

setLink();

window.addEventListener('resize', setLink);
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a JavaScript variable called screen.width which is pretty self explanatory, it gets the screens width. So for example:

```
if (screen.height > screen.width) {
  //This means your on a mobile device so if you wanted people on mobile to go to mobile support instead of desktop support you could use this method
}
else {
  //do something
}
//or you could just
if (screen.width == 1360) {
  //Do this for people with only 1360 pixel wide screens
}
else {
  //Do this for people without 1360 pixel screens
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working for me in my pen. Could you help me with it?

Comment: @mb_dc2008 Yeah! So what is the precise objective your trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to link to an anchored component on a wordpress page (https://example.com/page#canvas). On smaller screens (below 768) the canvas element is replaced with a video component and the anchor link changes (https://example.com/page#video). I would like to link to the canvas element if the user is on a larger screen but link to the video component if on a smaller screen.